# mmap + unity = sHandle is invalid

Tags: c#, python, winapi, unity-game-engine, mmap

I'm trying to establish a connection between python and unity, using c# & a **memory mapped file** (mmf). The python project uses the mmap import & writes it on "Interface.bin".

To interpret the changes happening in Interface.bin I followed the following example:

```
          public class PlaneController: MonoBehaviour {
          //Shared Memory
          [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
          static extern SafeFileHandle OpenFileMapping(
           uint dwDesiredAccess,
           bool bInheritHandle,
           string lpName);

          [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
          static extern IntPtr MapViewOfFile(
          SafeFileHandle hFileMappingObject,
          UInt32 dwDesiredAccess,
          UInt32 dwFileOffsetHigh,
          UInt32 dwFileOffsetLow,
          UIntPtr dwNumberOfBytesToMap);

          string szMapName = "UnityFileMappingObject";

          const UInt32 STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED = 0x000F0000;
          const UInt32 SECTION_QUERY = 0x0001;
          const UInt32 SECTION_MAP_WRITE = 0x0002;
          const UInt32 SECTION_MAP_READ = 0x0004;
          const UInt32 SECTION_MAP_EXECUTE = 0x0008;
          const UInt32 SECTION_EXTEND_SIZE = 0x0010;
          const UInt32 SECTION_ALL_ACCESS = (STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED | SECTION_QUERY |
              SECTION_MAP_WRITE |
              SECTION_MAP_READ |
              SECTION_MAP_EXECUTE |
              SECTION_EXTEND_SIZE);
          const UInt32 FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS = SECTION_ALL_ACCESS;
          private SafeFileHandle sHandle;
          private IntPtr hHandle;
          private IntPtr pBuffer;
          private int sharedInputCount;
          bool attachSuccessful;
       //
          int count;
          int X0;
          int Y0;
          int X1 = -1;
          int Y1 = -1;
          int SQ0 = -1;
          int SQ1 = -1;

      void Start (){
      sHandle = new SafeFileHandle(hHandle, true);
              sharedInputCount = 0;
              attachSuccessful = Attach(szMapName, 256);
      }

      unsafe public bool Attach(string SharedMemoryName, UInt32 NumBytes)
          {
              if (!sHandle.IsInvalid) return false;
              sHandle = OpenFileMapping(FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, false, SharedMemoryName);
              Debug.Log("Shared mem open: ");
              if (sHandle.IsInvalid) return false;
              Debug.Log("Shared mem open SUCCESS: ");
              pBuffer = MapViewOfFile(sHandle, FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, 0, 0, new UIntPtr(NumBytes));
              Debug.Log("Shared mem mapped: ");
              return true;
          }

      unsafe public void Detach()
          {
              if (!sHandle.IsInvalid && !sHandle.IsClosed )
              {
                  //CloseHandle(hHandle); //fair to leak if can't close
                  sHandle.Close();
              }
              pBuffer = IntPtr.Zero;
              //lBufferSize = 0;
          }
          void Update()
          {
              if (!attachSuccessful)
              {
                  attachSuccessful = Attach(szMapName, 256);
                  return;
              }
          }
       void FixedUpdate ()
          {
              //get Shared memory Input
              if (!attachSuccessful)
              {
                  return;
              }
              count = Marshal.ReadInt32(pBuffer, 0);
              X0 = Marshal.ReadInt32(pBuffer, 4);
              Y0 = Marshal.ReadInt32(pBuffer, 8);
              X1 = Marshal.ReadInt32(pBuffer, 12);
              Y1 = Marshal.ReadInt32(pBuffer, 16);
              SQ0 = Marshal.ReadInt32(pBuffer, 20);
              SQ1 = Marshal.ReadInt32(pBuffer, 24);
      }
  }
```

In unity I get the **"trying to attach" & "Shared mem open"** but afterwards the **sHandle seems to be invalid**. My project settings have already been set to .NET 2.0 (instead of the subset)

The python files, as well as the Interface.bin are **situated inside the scripts folder**. After inspecting the mmap with a windows process tool I can verify it exists.

Any idea as to why my sHandle is invalid? This kind of is my missing link!

EDIT: the GetLastError returns

```
ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
2 (0x2)
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Since the memorymapped file lives in the memory, can I assume it's not created?

Comment: [mcve] required. Specifically, we need to see the error handling (which you skipped). Why use `SetLastError = true` when you don't evaluate the last error code where necessary? Also make sure to reduce the example to its absolute *minimum*.

Comment: My apologies. It is my first post in a language I just got to know 5 days ago.
Small update)

Comment: This doesn't help. Please provide a [mcve]. It needs to be *complete* and *minimal*. Merely posting that `GetLastError` returns some error code, at some unspecified point isn't helpful. For all we know, you might be calling it at the wrong time. Or call `GetLastError` directly, which is wrong as well. If readers of your question have to guess, it isn't going to be useful to future visitors.

Comment: It turns out that windows needs a 'Local\\' path in order to be able to fetch the mmap. I also had to give the mmap a "tagName" in Python.